# I need example how to add Controls to a Panel in an ASP.NET Web page programmatically

Tags: asp.net

As example, I need my Panel to contain various number of CheckBoxes.

Comment: You want to add the control panel to your web page huh ?

Answer (score 1):

i am answering according to title...

```
CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
panel1.Controls.Add(chk1);
```

You can add as many as you want using this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reword the question so that we understand what you are after.
What it sounds like you want is a load of checkbox list controls.  Multiple ones...
If so in asp.net just add a checkboxlist control and then add check boxes to the list control.  You can then tell each check box what list control it belongs to.